# In Sublime Text, how can I jump and select to the next empty line between paragraphs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text, selection, keyboard-navigation

In Sublime Text, what's the best way to jump between / over paragraphs?

For example, if my cursor is on the empty line after `bar`'s `end` statement, how do I jump to the empty line between `foo` and `bar`?

```
def foo
  ...
end

def bar
 ...
end

^
```

And how do I do this while also selecting `bar`, as if I held down shift while moving the caret up line-by-line with the arrow keys?

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/jump-to-next-empty-line/3000/3) in the Sublime Text forum, with contributions from jps, tobia, adzenith, and others.

The best way to achieve this is adding the following keybindings to your `.sublime-keymap` file, which can be opened via Preferences -> Key Bindings in the top menu. You don't need to install any Packages.

```
 {
    "keys": ["alt+up"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": {
      "by": "stops",
      "empty_line": true,
      "forward": false
    }
  },

  {
    "keys": ["alt+down"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": {
      "by": "stops",
      "empty_line": true,
      "forward": true
    }
  },

  {
    "keys": ["alt+shift+up"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": {
      "by": "stops",
      "empty_line": true,
      "forward": false,
      "extend": true
    }
  },

  {
    "keys": ["alt+shift+down"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": {
      "by": "stops",
      "empty_line": true,
      "forward": true,
      "extend": true
    }
  },
```

On Linux, the `select_lines` command to create multiple carets is already bound to "alt+shift+up/down" by default, so you need to remap it if you want to avoid losing that shortcut. I recommend "alt+control+up/down" which is unused by default.

```
  {
    "keys": ["alt+control+up"],
    "command": "select_lines",
    "args": { "forward": false }
  },

  {
    "keys": ["alt+control+down"],
    "command": "select_lines",
    "args": { "forward": true }
  }
```

The situation might be different on Windows and OSX. If you have info on that, please leave a comment and I'll update the answer!